# How get attribute values in DOM elements with jquery, having a ng-repeat in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, svg

i'm pretty new with angularJS, i'd like to figure out how to execute a jquery function that allow me to draw an SVG on each image's div container that has an ID "scoped" through ng-repeat directive.

**partial.html**

```
<div class="cover-cont" ng-repeat="project in projects" dv-list-projects>
            <a href="#/project/{{project.slug}}">
                <div class="cover" id="{{project.slug}}">

                   <img ng-src="{{project.custom_fields.projectCover}}">
                </div>
            </a>
</div>
```

my jquery function:

```
            $('.cover').each(function(i, e){

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

            var iw = $(this).find('img').width();
            var ih = $(this).find('img').height();

            var draw = SVG(id).size(iw , ih);
            var svgImg = draw.image(img).size(iw,ih);

            svgImg.filter(function(add) {
                console.log('filter');
                add.colorMatrix('saturate', 0.5);
            });

            var polygon = draw.polygon('0,0 '+ iw +',0 0,'+ih);
            svgImg.clipWith(polygon);
            });
```

So, i need to get src, Id of .cover div, but i still have {{project.slug}} like string instead the value of this scope for the id of .cover.

hope you can give some best approaches about this argument.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular way to do this is with a directive, instead of using jquery directly in your controller to reference the element, the directive gives you the element.

```
module.directive("myCover", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            project: "=myCover"
        },
        template: "<div class='cover'><img ng-src='{{project.custom_fields.projectCover}}' /></div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            // Find the image, you could also modify this slightly so
            // that the directive goes on the image
            var img = element.find("img");

            // Handle when the image is changed
            img.on("load" draw);

            // Apply your manipulations
            function draw() {
                var iw = img.width();
                // logic
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then you would use this in your html with

```
<div my-cover="project" />
```

You can find more about directives and what all of that does at: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

(Sorry haven't tested that or put in a fiddle, quick reply :>)

Comment: i've modified the scope param to '=myCover' and added a curly braces into ng-src, but now can't get the width of element, it returns 0. despite of i can see it into console detection.

Comment: Hi, sorry yeah there was a couple of mistakes in there which have been updated, forgot to take into account the ng-src being loaded, was a flying reply before I moved around. Created a fiddle with an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/gjQ3A/2/

Comment: thanks for the correction. i don't know if it's correct but i've added `scope.$watch` into link function.

Comment: Watching the value for changes is fine too, it may fire too soon though as you need the image to load before you can get its dimensions. You could set the handler with `img.one("load", fn);` inside the watch `scope.$watch("project.importantProperty", fn);`. This would allow you to watch for other changes to redraw on if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular js

your controller may be `$scope.projects = data ; // response from service`

so you can use `this.project.slug`

it is not a good coding practice mixing jquery with angular js